# Docker Compose php/mysql can't connect to mysql

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, redbean

I try to create a simple multi container app according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app) with docker compose and deploy it on azure.

Folder structure:

```
-rootfolder:
   docker-compose.yml
   -webapp:
        index.php
        Dockerfile
```

./docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./webapp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: php:7.2-apache
    volumes:
      - ./webapp:/var/www/html/
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db:3306
      DB_USER: dbuser
      DB_PASSWORD: dbpassword
  db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     ports:
      - 3306:3306
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somerootpw
       MYSQL_DATABASE: dbname
       MYSQL_USER: dbuser
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: dbpassword

volumes: 
  db_data: #like in the official documentation empty
```

./webapp/Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY . /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80
```

./webapp/index.php:

```
<?php 
require 'rb.php';
R::setup( 'mysql:host=db:3306;dbname=dbname', 'dbuser', 'dbpassword' );
$post = R::dispense( 'post' );
$post->title = 'My holiday';
$id = R::store( $post );
$post = R::load( 'post', $id );
print_r($post);
?>
```

Now I do `$ docker compose up` and visit http://localhost:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: Could not connect to database
> (dbname).

- What am I missing to first make this run locally? and second, do I need to change anything so it works on azure right away?

Answer (score 0):

please try authenticate with root password?

if you also try to connect on the DB container, I think you will have the same error, unless o
`chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql`

this is explained here in this post https://doc4dev.com/en/create-a-web-site-php-apache-mysql-in-5-minutes-with-docker/

I think if you try to use root:somerootpw it shall work.
At least you can give it a try :)

also you can maybe try to do a dockerfile for mysql image:

```
FROM mysql:latest
USER root
RUN chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you affiliated in any way with the linked website? If so, please note that when linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.